# How to start the preferred audio player via the command line?

Tags: command-line, audio-player

My bash script should call the user preferred audio player instead of vlc or mplayer directly. How can I call it from bash? I assume something like

```
audio-player --play music.mp3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use XDG open, it should open file with default application:

```
xdg-open music.mp3
```

From [xdg-open man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html):

> NAME
>
> ```
>    xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    xdg-open {file | URL}
>
>    xdg-open {--help | --manual | --version}
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>    URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>    browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred
>    application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http
>    and https URLs.
>
>    xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not
>    recommended to use xdg-open as root.
> ```

Comment: For more see [`man xdg-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html).

Comment: Is there something similar for folders/directories?